# Sorting Data Range Based on Arbitrarily Ordered String Key Through Google Scripts

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

I am trying to sort values of column `A` depending on the values at column `B` ordered by matching keys at column `E` expected results are in column `C`

I can achieve this through [formula described here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/126621/how-can-i-sort-a-data-range-in-google-sheets-based-on-an-data-range)

```
=SORT(A2:A;ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(B2:B;E2:E;0));1)
```

I am seeking a google script answer to enhance its automation by using it through `onEdit` trigger. I can sort column `A` according to column `B` alphabetically through this pseudocode snippet. I need help on attaching this the numeric order of `sort key`

```
var sortRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,lastCol)
sortRange.sort({column: 2, ascending: false});
```

Thanks in advance

====== Update ======
Found a Solution Thanks to ziganotschka

```
    // Retrieve Keys&Range
    var sortKeys = ss.getRange(2, 5, 3, 1).getValues().flat();
    var sortRange = ss.getRange(2,1,lastRow,2).getValues();
    // Set an index to each row according to its relation to the search keys
    for (var ii=0; ii < sortRange.length; ii++){
      var index =  sortKeys.indexOf(sortRange[ii][1]);
      sortRange[ii].push(index);
    }
    // Sort the array ascending by index
    activeCell.setValue(sortRange[0][2]);
    sortRange.sort(function(a,b) {
      var varA = a[2];
      var varB = b[2];
      return varA == varB ? 0 : varA > varB ? -1 : 1;
    }); 
    // Reduce the array to the sorted values of Column A
    var sortedColumn = sortRange.map(function(i){return [i[0]];});  
    //set values into column C
    ss.getRange(2, 6, sortedColumn.length, 1).setValues(sortedColumn);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort by script instead of formula, you have to do it differently

- `sortRange.sort` will sort you current spreadsheet contents rather than outputting the sorted version in a new column
- Instead you need to retrieve the values as an array and perform a Javascript array sorting function on it: [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- Also, if you want to sort by searchkeys in column E, rather than alphabetically / numerically, you need to append to the retrieved array an index column based on a row's relation tot he search key
- The index can be retrieved with [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- After you sort the three column array (column A, column B and the new index column), reduce the array to the sorted values column and set it into column C with [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Sample:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = 2;
  var sortRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow-1,lastCol).getValues();
  //retrieve the keys in column E
  var keys = sheet.getRange(2, 5, lastRow, 1).getValues().flat();
  for (var i =0; i < sortRange.length; i++){
    //set an index to each row according to its relation to the search keys
    var index =  keys.indexOf(sortRange[i][1]);
    sortRange[i].push(index);
  }
  //sort the array ascending by index
  sortRange.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a[2] - b[2]
  });  
  //reduce the array to the sorted values of Column A
  var sortedColumn = sortRange.map(function (i){return [i[0]];});  
  //set values into column C
  sheet.getRange(2, 3, sortedColumn.length, 1).setValues(sortedColumn);  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had a little problem with sort but managed to solve. Updating the question with solution based on your answer.